# TinyMCE Notifications Custom Css

Tags: css, notifications, tinymce

I have read this document  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-custom-notifications/   but i have not found where i can change the text color, icon color, background color.  Currently the background and text are so light that users cannot read anything in the notification box, so i need to make some changes.  But i have not been successfull.

First I added this code to my site css. (it is what i see in the console)

```
.tox .tox-notification--info {
background-color: #d2cbcb; /* off white */
border-color: #000000;
color: #000000;
}

.tox .tox-notification--info p {
color: #000000;
}

.tox .tox-notification--info svg {
fill: #000000;
}
```

And no effect even after hard cache clear. Then i put that same code in a custom css file and used the tinymce content_css:  like so

```
 content_css: 'sbc_custom.css',
```

if found the file but still no change.   I can change the values in the console only.  How do i get the css to work?  (i am using TinyMCE version 5)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to build a custom skin either by [building it yourself as outlined in the docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-skin/), or use the [TinyMCE 5 skin tool](http://skin.tiny.cloud/t5/). The TinyMCE styles are written in LESS and you basically modify variables to customize the look and feel of TinyMCE. To style the notifications, the [following variables are available to you](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/oxide/src/less/theme/components/notification/notification.less).

If you're using the skin tool, switch to the advanced mode and copy & paste the following into  `@notification-warn-background-color: red;` at the end of the existing variables which should turn the yellow notification red in the preview.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  Links were a big help.  Do you happen to have a link to get TinyMCE 5.5 working on a normal modal, just a basic HTML modal, i dont use jquery or bootstrap so those solutions dont work for me.  Thanks :)