# I want to override the inline style with !important

Tags: css, tinymce

The style element created in tinymce is overwritten by the defaultcss, so I want the "!important" attribute to be automatically added to the style element.
How do I automatically add an "!important"?

Comment: Well this depends on how the inline-style is being added. please clarify

Comment: Try to improve your question, show your code and be more specific, please. You can follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This answer from [LostKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8542588/lostkeys) may be helpful: [TinyMCE Notifications Custom Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842837/tinymce-notifications-custom-css)

You can put together a custom skin that should overwrite the defaultcss. The above stack overflow answer has a list or resources on how to do this. If you have a particular element that is not working, even with the !important element, you could try "!tox" as well.